# Docusign - Unable to get signature image from android envelope

Tags: android, image, docusignapi, signature

Hi I am using this api (`/restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/recipients/{recipientId}/signature_image`) to get signature image from envelopes created by web, IOS and Android but in case of android I am getting this response 404 But it exist in docusign account envelopes in the completed list

```
{
    "errorCode": "RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND",
    "message": "The URL provided does not resolve to a resource."
}
```

here is the code

```
public function getSignature(){

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/account_id/envelopes/envelope_id/recipients/recipient_id/signature_image');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);



    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = 'Content-Type: image/gif';
    $headers[] = 'Accept: image/gif';
    $headers[] = 'Authorization: Bearer JWT Token';
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
      echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
    }
    curl_close($ch);

    if (strpos($result, 'errorCode') !== false) {
    return $result;
}

    return $response['data'] = $result;
    // return view('signature', $response);
  }
```

Comment: Posting your code will better help someone help you.

Comment: Added the code too now.